# Execute jar file with command line on Windows Server 2012

Tags: java, coldfusion, jar, command-prompt, coldfusion-10

I'm trying to execute a .jar file to update my Coldfusion server but when I type the following command into the command prompt (running as administrator) it tells me that the system cannot find the specified file.

`W:\CF10> java -jar <hotfix11>.jar`

The file is located in the CF10 folder on the W drive. I've also tried putting the full file path in the <> of the command but had the same results.

Any thoughts on what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: What is the exact error message that you are getting?  The problem might be that the command prompt cannot locate the `java` executable itself because you are running from the `CF10` directory. Not the jar file.

Comment: It just returns the message "The system cannot find the specified file". Should I be running it from a different directory?

Comment: No, but I'm guessing that you need to include the path to the java executable from that directory. Something like `W:\CF10> "c:\program files\java\jre7\bin\java" -jar <hotfix11>.jar`

Comment: Aren't hot fixes done within the CF Admin in CF 10?

Comment: @JamesMohler They can be, but in some cases, it is not possible to download them. I work on a project where one test server does not have access outside of out network so we need to manually apply the hot fixes.

Comment: If you're getting a message saying 'The system cannot find the specified file', then the issue is NOT that Java isn't on the PATH.  If it wasn't, you'd get an error `'java' is not recognised as an internal or external command...` instead.  Also, if the JAR file wasn't being found, you'd get an error `Unable to access jarfile ...`.  So it seems Java and the JAR can both be found.  I don't know the first thing about ColdFusion, but if I was in your situation I would use Sysinternals Process Monitor to see if I could find out exactly what file wasn't being found.

Comment: I would try and rule out the obvious causes first by 1) using an absolute path for both the `java.exe` and `.jar` **and** 2) running a `dir c:\path\to\theFile.ext` on those paths first - to ensure they are valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Java bin directory is not part of the Windows system PATH by default. Because you are attempting to run the Java executable from your `W:\CF10` directory you are getting that error. The error is not referencing the JAR file but the Java executable itself. Windows can't find it from that directory so you need to include the path in your command line.

Something like this for example:

```
W:\CF10> "c:\program files\java\jre7\bin\java" -jar <hotfix11>.jar
```

You can test if the Java bin directory is in your system PATH by simply typing `java` at your command prompt from the `W:\CF10>` directory. If you get the same error than it is not. If you see the command line options for the Java command then it is and you have some other problem.

James just made a valid comment - for ColdFusion 10 hotfixes are applied via the ColdFusion administrator.